# Video.js smooth playback

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, video.js

I've implemented video.js to load MP4s from Amazon s3.

I'm really struggling to get smooth playback, even on a small (7mb) video. It's very jumpy and stop -starting.  The internet connection here is fast, and if I download it directly it downloads instantly.

I've tried several things, lastest is buffering with:

```
var player = videojs('video');
        player.on("ended", function(){ closeVideo(); });
        player.ready(function(){checkBuffer(player); });
    videoPlaying = true;

}

function checkBuffer(player){
    var howMuchIsDownloaded = player.bufferedPercent();
    if(howMuchIsDownloaded >  0.3){
    player.play();  //start playing the video 
    }else{
    setTimeout(checkBuffer, 100, player);
    }

}
```

This works but it's still very jumpy after playing.

Video is constructed:

```
    $('body').append(
             " <video id='video' class='video-js' preload width='100%' height='100%'"
            + "     data-setup='{}'>"
            + "   <source src='http://cdn.example.com/"+ video +"' type='video/x-m4v' />"
            +"  </video>"
    );
```

Any clues how to get smooth video like in the video.js examples?

Comment: Have you tried setting the buffer to 10ms or 1000ms timeout?

Comment: Ohh no. DO you know how to set this in video.js ? Can't find the parameter in the docs.

Comment: setTimeout(checkBuffer, 100, player);

Comment: oh right. Yeah that doesn't help. Even when it's got 30% loaded it's still jumpy. It might be an encoding issue, that's the next thing I'll try.

Comment: What browser(s) are you seeing this in? It does sound like either an encoding or bandwidth issue. If you can set up live example that could help debug. (e.g. [a jsbin](http://jsbin.com/axedog/edit))

Answer (score 0):

THanks for your help. It was an encoding issue. I re-encoded the video and it's fine. Runs smooth.